# apport-collect <bug_no> returning "No route to host"

Tags: proxy, apport

I just filed [a bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1296270), for which I have been asked to submit the output of:

```
 apport-collect 1296270
```

However, when I run this command, I get the following output:

```
ERROR: connecting to Launchpad failed: [Errno 113] No route to host
You can reset the credentials by removing the file "/home/jobin/.cache/apport/launchpad.credentials"
```

However, I have checked that my internet connection is working fine. It may be noted that I am behind a proxy server that requires authentication to access internet and have set the proxy settings in `/etc/environment` and in my `~/.bashrc` file.

I have verified that the settings are reflecting on the terminal using `echo $http_proxy` and `echo $https_proxy`. I can also successfully use `traceroute google.com` in 17 ms.

How do I solve this, to successfully run `apport-collect <bug_no>`? Is it a bug or is there a wordaround?

**P.S.**: I could confirm that I can run `apport-collect <bug_no>` and submit the results to launchpad on a system not behind manual proxy.